# Hictop 3d printer upgrades?

Tags: abs, heated-bed, prusa-i3, hbp

Where can I go to upgrade this printer? It's a hictop prusa i3 3d printer. Where do you buy heated beds suitable for ABS and PLA? Also, what kind of extruder do you guys think I should buy?
[image]

This is were I bought it from. 
[http://www.amazon.com/HICTOP-Desktop-Accuracy-Self-Assembly-Tridimensional/dp/B00N7I1ZVU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N7I1ZVU)

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it is primarily opinion-based, and purchasing advice is considered off-topic.

Comment: I agree with Tom, and has voted for a close.

Comment: Also the question has poor detail. We don't have any information on the research the TO has done and what else has to be considered why this question cannot be answered by internet search engines.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your electronics are open source (such as RAMPS), you can buy upgrades and spare parts from pretty much every 3D printer spare part provider out there, as long as they suit your needs and the specs of your printer.

In other words, if you want make a headbed upgrade, find some bed that i.e.:

- Fit the size of your printer
- Can be mounted properly
- Can be used with your current electronics (and possibly software)

In general, most DIY hobby desktop 3D printers today use more or less the same components mounted in various ways.